# How do I replace a subscriber with an Observer?

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

[This](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1535#issuecomment-50648178) issue on GitHub pretty much sums it up. I'am using a `timer()` with a recurring schedule of 1 second to perform a certain task. I pair it up with a `Subscriber` to subscribe the intervals. When a certain model runs out of data, I unsubscribe it & wait for new arrivals. When they data is populated again, I try to subscribe again but it doesn't work. It turns out whena `Subscriber` has been unsub'd, I can't use it again. So I must replace it with an `Observer`. A newbie here, I've no idea how to do that. tried looking at examples, they just confused me further.

How do I replace the following code to function with an `Observer` instead?

```
private timer = timer(1000, 1000);

// A timer subscription that keeps sending new images to the observer
timerSubscription = new Subscriber(() => {

    // Check if there is an element in the list
    if (this.head != null) {

      // If the current node at head is a folder, unsubscribe the listener
      if (this.head.data['id'].startsWith('folder')) {
        this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }

      // Pop a node from the list and pass on to observer
      this.observer.next(this.this$PiFrame.pop());

    } else {

      // If no nodes are left, unsubscribe from the timer
      this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();

      console.log('No items left on the queue. Deactivating timer subscription.');
    }
  }, e => {}, () => {});
```

and I subscribe like so :

```
    ...
    // Setup a timer to pop every 1000 ms
    this.timer.subscribe(this.this$PiFrame.timerSubscription);
    ...
    // If no nodes are left, unsubscribe from the timer
    this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the subscription the way you do, let the `Observable` return the subscription.

Keep your logic in a function, like so:

```
  doWhatever() {
    console.log("tick")

    // Check if there is an element in the list
    if (this.head != null) {

      // If the current node at head is a folder, unsubscribe the listener
      if (this.head.data['id'].startsWith('folder')) {
        this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }

      // Pop a node from the list and pass on to observer
      this.observer.next(this.this$PiFrame.pop());

    } else {

      // If no nodes are left, unsubscribe from the timer
      this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();

      console.log('No items left on the queue. Deactivating timer subscription.');
    }
  }
```

Then, when you want to subscribe:

```
this.timerSubscription = this.timer.subscribe(() => this.doWhatever());
```

This can be used repeatedly, as each `subscribe` generates a new `Subscription`

Comment: Thanks 994! Works like a charm now! :D